# Fit defined number of isometric tile into any screen resolution

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, isometric

I want to display an isometric grid in a canvas while having a defined number of tiles per row/column.

At the moment, I draw an orthogonal grid into a rotated (45°) and scaled (height/2) canvas, which leads to an isometric grid.

Demo [here](http://ultima14.com/Truc/plateau.php)

At first, I wanted to draw a large grid that would fit the whole screen and moving it in order to get this : 
[image]

But i'm clueless about how to always get the same number of tiles and the same starting index for each screen resolution. The player should always see 14 * 20 tiles.